# Authenticate SVN users using local Linux Groups?

Tags: linux, authentication, svn, usergroups

Does anyone know how I can configure svn to use local linux groups to authenticate users?

For example if we have:

devrepo = should be accessible by groups 'dev' and 'prod'

productionrepo = should be accessible by only the 'prod' group

Due to security limitations of the platform concerned, we cannot use Apache so only svnserve or plain old svn+ssh are the possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

`svn+ssh` relies entirely on the filesystem's permissions.  This is a good thing in your instance.

Alas, I'm not familiar enough with Linux's [ACL support](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl5_acl.htm) (rather than older UNIX-style file permissions) to help you set the appropriate ACL permissions... and you'll need ACLs to assign a directory's permissions for more than one group.

`svnserve` is right out, as it uses its own users and groups.

Comment: yup thats what I thought ... and we are using svn+ssh right now and to maintain seperate user/group lists for 100+ users and 10 repos would have been a nightmare!

So yes svn+ssh works great right now for us in prod where we are the only ones with access, but now we have to share some repos with dev's and keep them out of prod repos where we have sensitive passwords etc